# How to access the value of variable outside the function in node js (node js with postgresql)

Tags: node.js, postgresql

```
var pg = require('pg');
var conString = "postgres://postgres:abk@localhost/bot";

var res = [];

pg.connect(conString, function(err, client, done) {

    if(err) {
        return console.error('error fetching client', err);
    }
    client.query('SELECT * FROM bot.questions', function(err, result)  
    {

        done();

        if(err) {
            return console.error('error running query', err);
        }

        res.push(result.rows[0]);
        console.log(res);    //inside function scope
   });
});

console.log(res);    // outside function scope
```

"**console.log()**" which has called inside the function gives proper resulting array, but outside function the same array variable shows an **empty** array. I have tried lot of things, such as callbacks, promises functionalities in node js but was not able to see the resulting "res" outside the function.
Please suggest me how do I make that "**res**" variable accessible from outside of function.

**NOTE:** Specifically, I need "**console.log(res)**" to print the "res" outside of function as mentioned in above code.

Answer (score 0):

res variable is indeed accessible outside the function, as it is defined outside the function

res variable is indeed populated outside of the function, as it is seen as populated inside the function

root cause of your problem is that the outside print happens chronologically earlier than the inside activity, as the function is asynchronous, the call comes out immediately, and proceeds to execute the last line in the code.

If you are just particular about getting the value outside, it is indeed is the case

If you are wanting to just print the value outside, use a delayed callback in which to print the content

If you are wanting to post-process the value outside, you will need to link the connect function with a next function, through synchronization primitives.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I understand what you said. I don't want to use delayed callback. Can you just explain me with my same example how do I pass this "**res**" to some other function with specific array value. My concern was I wanted to make "**res**" accessible in any functions in file. but how do I do that?  As I mentioned previously i have tried callback functions to access the same "**res**" value but not able to do that. Please give me example here considering my case how do I pass this "res" to some other function.

Comment: `app.post('/results/', function (req, res) { }`  I have this function, I need to pass that "**res**" to this function. Please tell how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

As explained before, the query's result will exist only when the callback is fired, so it won't make sense accessing it in a part of the code that would execute before that.
It seems like you need to read a bit about node's asynchronous programming.
I suggest you read about promises and generators.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution finally, I have created seperate file for db config along with resulting array of values using callback function to export. Here is the "**db.js**" file which I have created.

```
var pg = require('pg');
var conString = "postgres://postgres:abk@localhost/chatbot";

var resp = [];

function executeQuery (callback) {

    pg.connect(conString, function(err, client, done) {
        if(err) {
            return console.error('error fetching client', err);
        }
        client.query('SELECT * FROM bot.questions', function(err, result) {

        done();

        if(err) {
            return console.error('error running query', err);
        }

        resp.push(result.rows[0]);
        // console.log(res);

        callback(resp);

       });
   });
};

exports.executeQuery = executeQuery;
```

and this I have imported into my "**app.js**" like bellow

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var request = require('request')
var app = express()
var db = require('./db')

app.post('/webhook/', function (req, res) {
    db.executeQuery(function ( resp) {
        console.log(resp);
    });
});
```

This is how I can now access "resp" as resulting array, and can pass it to any function as an argument wherever required. 
There is specific need as per my requirements to make the db config file separate from app.js file, otherwise I know it can also be manipulated in same app.js file.
So finally, This works for me perfectly.

**This is what a kind of example I was expecting.** But I found it by myself.

Anyways thanks for your involvement, and suggessions.